# Is there an easy way to convert seconds into an ISO 8601 format for use in the schema.org video metadata?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I'm trying to use what Google suggests for html markup on video search results. They suggest using schema.org markup for SEO purposes.

The following line is for duration: 
`<meta itemprop="duration" content="T1M33S" />`

The time must be in ISO 8601 format according to Google and Schema.org -  "The duration of the video in ISO 8601 format."

I have some jquery that pulls the duration of the video from the html5 video element. The duration extracted is in seconds.

Whats the best way to convert seconds into ISO 8601 format?

Is there something in C#, Javascript, or JQuery to easily accomplish this task?

Thanks

Comment: Somehow I get the feeling that if you're going to "pull the duration of a video with jQuery", no search engine is going to pick that up.

Comment: Im extracting the duration data from the video element and loading it into the following tag.  <meta itemprop="duration" content="T1M33S" />

Comment: That's true. My brain is mush. I'm trying to figure out the best way to get a video duration from a mp4 and display it on that metatag. I just need google to see it.

Comment: If I extract the duration and write out a metatag using javascript on pageload, google spiders should see the markup right?

Comment: Google does execute *some* JavaScript but loading and parsing an entire embedded video sounds a bit too much to expect. Not going to believe it until I see it.

Comment: `PT1M33S` is equivalent to `PT93S` and both are valid ISO 8601 durations.  All you need to do is: `"PT" + seconds + "S"`.

Comment: Gilly you pretty much answered my question. In order to convert seconds to ISO 8601 I just need to: "PT" + seconds + "S".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# you could use a TimeSpan and a custom format string:

```
var duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secs);

string iso8601 = duration.ToString("'P'd'DT'h'H'm'M's'S'");
```

(n.b. I didn't actually run this)

Answer (score -2):

Jquery is not necessary for getting this result. However JavaScript can be used for this.

First you can use the `toISOString()` function in the date class:

```
var date = new Date();
date.toISOString();
```

However this is not supported in all browsers because it is part of ECMAScript5 (most browsers do, but err on the side of caution). So you can write a backup to do this, like so:

```
if ( !Date.prototype.toISOString ) {
  ( function() {

    function pad(number) { // Add leading zero if necessary
      var r = String(number);
      if ( r.length === 1 ) {
        r = '0' + r;
      }
      return r;
    }

    Date.prototype.toISOString = function() { // Return the date as a ISO string
      return this.getUTCFullYear()
        + '-' + pad( this.getUTCMonth() + 1 )
        + '-' + pad( this.getUTCDate() )
        + 'T' + pad( this.getUTCHours() )
        + ':' + pad( this.getUTCMinutes() )
        + ':' + pad( this.getUTCSeconds() )
        + '.' + String( (this.getUTCMilliseconds()/1000).toFixed(3) ).slice( 2, 5 )
        + 'Z';
    };

  }() );
}
```

Now all you need to do is run the javascript.